# Javascript, track iframes redirecting top window

Tags: javascript, iframe

Since there is no way to prevent an iframe from redirecting the top frame besides sandboxing which prevents other features required for viewability tracking I would like to track redirects. Since one site can have more than one iframe, it could be any of these.

Is there any way to track/find out which one (specific iframe) caused the top frame redirect?

Here is a sandbox (use browser console and enable preserve log):

[image: Edit 3v50wqxz66]

**Note** the iframe content is usually cross domain. For ease of use its within the sandox.

Comment: Will the iframes `src` be on the same domain as the top frame?

Comment: the sandbox attribute allows control of wich features you want enabled... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe so you could enable everything except allow-top-navigation

Answer (score 5):

We can access to the iframe content with somethig like `iframe.contentWindow.document` but this is possible if we observe [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Another approach could be setting a [`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) header like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src http://example.com">
```

This header in the parent page prevents to load sites different to http://example.com in frames, There is also a way to [report](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri) the refuse behavior sending a post but unfortunately can't be setting with `<meta>` tag (it's only server side). With this approach we have to perform a white list, so I think maybe it's not useful in this case. But, if the white list is given the first time, is possible to set all sites available, so when the iframe redirect, browser will refuse to load it.

If it's not the case of same-origin and the possibility of performing a white list, then I think the better we can do is calling iframe [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onunload) event, unfortunately this event are going to be fired also when iframe page reloads not only on redirection. I think it's the closest approach. To achieve that, this code works.

```
var srcs = ["iframe2.html","iframe.html","iframe2.html"];


        for (let i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); 
                iframe.src = srcs[i]; 
                iframe.name = "i"+i; 
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                window["i"+i].onunload = function(){console.log("change "+i)}
        }
```

Of course `onunload` is fired the first time, when all iframes load, so redirections are 2th 3th and so on. But we could exclude that first case.

Here a full example https://codesandbox.io/s/o16yk7mqy , I've created iframe3.html that doesn't refresh neither reload to show clearly the point.  Also I've created a simple List of redirect or reload iframes.

**UPDATE**
As I understand now, what you want is to set iframes with [sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) property and whitelist all what you want but without `allow-top-navigation`,  something like:

```
<iframe src="iframe.html" sandbox="allow-script allow-forms allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

- This Example doesn't allow `allow-top-navigation` https://codesandbox.io/s/lpmv6wr6y9
- This Example here https://codesandbox.io/s/4x8v1mojq7 allow `allow-top-navigation` but **codesandbox** prevents the frame to redirect so if we try https://4x8v1mojq7.codesandbox.io/ that is the url created by **codesandbox**, we could see the top frame reload.

As I said in comments, at least Chrome 64.0.3282.167, when we delegate all but allow-top-navigation when the iframe attempt to redirect top frame, it throw an exception. The behavior is different in Firefox (at least 58.0.2). Firefox deny top navigation but continues with the code.

So, as conclusion the best approach in my opinion is or a combination of sanbox and onunload or just onunload. Of course, if it could be possible,  Content-Security-Policy is the safest and more flexible way. It depends of the implementation. It's almost impossible I think not to involve server side code to perform a perfect solution. There are white list to check, like this API https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/ and there are black list to check, look at this post https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32058/looking-for-url-blacklists-of-malicious-websites .

Comment: How does this help with identifying the iframe with the bad code/redirect?

Comment: @user2693017 i is the key of srcs, that is the iframe redirecting or reloading

Comment: If i = 0 it's iframe2.html , if i = 1 it's iframe.html and so on

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't helping in this case. 1. The content is cross site as mentioned in the question. 2. the snippet only fires on page reload/load but not when one of the iframe calls a top redirect. In this case nothing is firing :( see: https://transfer.sh/%28/InnNq/example.zip%29.tar.gz (codesandbox seems to have changed something, not allowing the redirect to happen in the sandbox)

Comment: @user2693017 The code in the .tar.gz doesn't reload top frame for me. The problem is that top navigation is't availible by default for cross origin, that's because I've never see that, I didn't undestant because of that. So I think your solution it's sanbox and whitelist all what you want except allow-top-navigation

Comment: @user2693017 look at this https://4x8v1mojq7.codesandbox.io/ in this case is explicit allowed so it works.

Comment: I'm aware of the sandboxing possiblity, unfortunately we can't use it because it prevents stuff like viewability tracking. Quoting the part about it from the question "besides sandboxing which prevents other features required for viewability tracking". Yes not having `allow-top-navigation` prevents viewability tracking from for example Moat.

Comment: @user2693017 as I said in the answer, with sandboxing property you could add all ,and exclude ONLY allow-top-navigation, then you could enjoy features required for viewability tracking.  If you execute this https://codesandbox.io/s/k10v1rm77r you are able to use "other features required for viewability tracking" and in a browser https://k10v1rm77r.codesandbox.io/

Comment: The issue is that if we do not set `allow-top-navigation`, viewability tracking doesn't work.

Comment: What's exactly the code are you trying? Because we are delegating all permissions except top navigation. Maybe we are missing some flag, but I've added all flags present in documentation. Something weird happen with allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation, chrome ask a user gesture and refer to this page https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629582019395584, so in the WICG discussion said that this gesture is "is still in the experimental stage", the fact is that chrome interrupts execution after this e.g ononload is not executed. On the other hand, firefox executes ononload.

Comment: Following the last comment, at least chrome 64.0.3282.167 executes restrictions as exceptions, so it doesn't execute any code after the exception.  If an iframe try to do something restricted, it throw an exception. At least firefox 58.0.2 don't, so we can use ononload or anything. Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: The issue is that as soon as we apply sandboxing some browser features which are used a lot do no longer work. See: https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js/issues/927#issuecomment-323793279

Comment: HTML5 storage engine? If that's true it's a really big problem. I think this issue should be solved soon,  in the meantime I'm more sure about whitelist, but the problem is still not a client only solution.

Comment: A whitelist is not practical in this case. For a blacklist we need to figure out the bad ones, hence why I'm looking for a way to find out which iframe was the cause/source..

Answer (score -1):

If you have control over all your frames you can implement interaction between frames with [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Flow:

1. Frame want to execute redirect - it sends a message to parent frame with redirect request.
2. Parent frame executing redirect and know which frame caused a redirect.

Parent:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    // show message source (your frame)
    console.log(event.source);

    const message = event.data;
    console.log(`Frame ID: ${message.frameId}`);

    if(message.messageType === "redirect") {
        window.location.href = message.redirectUrl;
    }
});
```

Child frame:

```
function redirect(url) {
    var message = {
        messageType: "redirect",
        frameId: "frame1"
        redirectUrl: url
    }
    window.parent.postMessage(message, "*");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately we don't. They are also cross domain.

Answer (score -1):

You can show a dialog box before redirecting to another domain/application and then the user can decide - to stay or leave the current application. You can also track the current target (i.e. iframe in your case).

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.location.href);
  return 'Stop redirection. Show dialog box.';
};
```

Answer (score -1):

From the individual iframes, can you set a cookie when the redirect happens? Say it happened from iframe1, you may set a cookie like

```
document.trackFrame = "FrameName=iframe1";
```

And once the redirect completes, can you try reading the cookie and there by determine which iframe caused the re-direct?

Comment: we do not control the content of the iframes